# Can't Install Ros2 Humble in ubuntu 23.04

Tags: ros-humble

After typing the command:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install curl -y
sudo curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.key -o /usr/share/keyrings/ros-archive-keyring.gpg
```

I am getting the output as:

```
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar InRelease
Hit:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-backports InRelease
Ign:5 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu lunar InRelease
Err:6 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu lunar Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu lunar Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Which is not enabling me to install ros-humble-desktop

Command:

```
sudo apt install ros-humble-desktop
```

Output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-humble-desktop
```

Answer (score 1):

The official ros repo does not provide binary packages for ros-humble for ubuntu-23. You need to either use ubuntu-22, build from source, or use docker.

The supported operating systems are documented here: https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-2000.html#humble-hawksbill-may-2022-may-2027

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try building from source or docker.